# Mongoose Population not working returning [Object] only not the fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Hey guys i am trying to fetch some data using `mongoose` from `MongoDB`.

it is not even populating the first level .

i will try my best to explain the situation below.

**I have my documents structure like below:**

**Schema[s]**

```
- UsersSchema

_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },    
userData : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DataType' }],


- DataTypeSchema

_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },    
data : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Data' }],


- DataSchema

_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },    
desc: String
```

**Filling the data :**

- in User > `userData : ["dataTypeID" , "dataTypeID" ]`
- in DataType > `data : ["dataID" , "dataID" ]`
- in Data > `desc: "pending"`

**The problem:**

i am trying to get the `desc` field of `Data` in my `User` document.

**What i tried :**

**1 try**

```
await User.find().populate('userData').lean();
```

response : it should populate the `DataType` model . instead i am looking at `[ [Object], [Object] ]`,

```
[{
    _id: 5b37aa4638a07505e809191a,
    userData: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0
}]
```

**2 try**

```
await User.find().populate('userData.data').lean();
```

i tried to do some thing which i don't know what it will do :D

response : and now it returns the id's of the `DataType` model

```
[{
   _id: 5b37aa4638a07505e809191a,
    userData: [ 5b35577759407235a4293020, 5b355fb5f51a0c1de0a3ab3d ],
    __v: 0
}]
```

**3 try**

then after reading the mongoose documentation :

```
await User.find().populate({
  path: 'userData',
  model: 'User',
  populate: {
    path: 'data',
    model: 'DataType',
  }
}).lean();
```

response : got and empty array `userData : []`

```
[{
 _id: 5b37aa4638a07505e809191a,
 userData: [ ],
 __v: 0
}]
```

**note** : if i remove the `model: 'User'` from the first populate i get the same response as `.populate('userData') = [ [Object], [Object] ],`

after allot of searching in answers i fond this : [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) to deep populate which is also working as the normal mongoose populate no effect at all.

it just doesn't make sense to me that why i can't even populate the `DataType` in the `User` :(

i hope any one will help me out in this weird kinda situation .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost going in the right direction with the 3rd try, but you gave the wrong model to populate from.

This is indeed a problem of `nested population` or `deep population`, as you found out, but you need to pass the correct `model` while populating,

Since `userData` is a `_id` of `DataType` collection, the `model` should be `DataType` and not `User`, similarly `data` is a `_id` of `Data` collection, the `model` should be `Data` not `DataType`. Make these changes and it should work as expected.

`model` in `.populate()` is to tell `mongodb/mongoose` which collection to populate it from.

Try this :

```
await User.find().populate({
  path: 'userData',
  model: 'DataType',
  populate: {
    path: 'data',
    model: 'Data',
  }
}).lean();
```

Also, Since you have defined `Ref` in the schema as well, you don't actually need to pass `model` in the `populate`, it will automatically know which collection to populate from.

Below query should work as well:

```
await User.find().populate({
  path: 'userData',
  populate: {
    path: 'data'
  }
}).lean();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so this all time i was getting the data :D because of console log  not printing the object out i was thinking that i am not getting the data :D

Comment: I thought that could be the problem as well, i just wanted to clear or your mistake as well :D